# I am making a file sorter and cant find a bug

Tags: python

So I want my code to find all the text files and put them into a list stored in a dict,

I made a dummy directory and put files in it

and then I use os to find the file extension and then I'm trying to put the in a list inside of a dict

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here's my code:

```
file_dict = {
    "Python": [],
    "Text": []
  }
  for file in files:
    split_file = os.path.splitext(file)
    ### sorting  they based on extension
    ### if file is text
    if split_file[1] == ".txt":
      file_dict["Text"].append(split_file[0])
  return file_dict
```

But when I call it from another function and print the text files, the list has nothing in it

output:

```
{'Text': []}
```

Comment: This isn't sorting, it's filtering. Sorting means putting things into a particular order, e.g. increasing or decreasing.

Comment: The example output you show is not possible given the code you gave us above. Are you sure you're running the code you think you are? The indentation of what you've shown is kind of all over the place, so it's very hard for us to assess what might be going wrong.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `glob.glob("/path/to/directory/*.txt")` to get all the text files?

Comment: Ripping random code out of functions and failing to include variables that the code has a dependency on is probably the fastest way to never get your problem solved. Minimal Reproducible Example ~ means you need to provide us with the minimal amount of executable code necessary to reproduce your problem. If this is your MRE, then your problem is simple - you haven't written any functioning code.

Answer (score 0):

I think `os.path.split()` is what you want.

Example:

```
files = ("/home/a.txt", "/home/b.txt")

file_dict = {
    "Python": [],
    "Text": []
  }
for file in files:
    split_file = os.path.split(file)
    if ".txt" in split_file[1]:
        file_dict["Text"].append(split_file[1])
print(file_dict)
```

output

```
{'Python': [], 'Text': ['a.txt', 'b.txt']}
```

If you use `os.path.splitext()`, you get root and extension such as `'/home/a'` and `'.txt'`.